# Django How to use drf-yasg in class-base view which is parent of all other views to generate swagger docs?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I'm using `drf-yasg` for swagger docs, but I'm using a `BaseView` which is the parent class view for all other views, thus all ***HTTP*** methods are written in `BaseView` so that children views don't need to implement these methods.

the problem is that when I added `@swagger_auto_schema` to baseView methods it didn't see the child attributes but the `BaseView`'s attributes which are empty.

The `BaseView`:

```py
class BaseView(APIView):
        model = models.Model
        serializer_class = serializers.Serializer
        description = ''
        id = openapi.Parameter('id', in_=openapi.IN_QUERY, type=openapi.FORMAT_UUID)
    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[id] ,responses={200: serializer_class},operation_description=description)
    def get(self, request, id=None, **kwargs):
                ....
    @swagger_auto_schema(request_body=serializer_class)
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
                ....
```

Then let's say I have this child view:

```py
class TestApi(BaseView):
    model = test
    description = 'This is test api'
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
```

In this approach ***Swagger*** is showing empty values for description and `serializer_class` because it doesn't see child values how to solve this without having to configure each view with ***HTTP*** methods and `@swagger_auto_schema`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a python file named api_docs.py and write a description of your API View of all methods.

   docs = {
   'View Name': {
   'post': 'your description',
   'list': '....description',
   }
   }
2. after that you have to import this into your view and add this.

   from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

   @method_decorator(name="HTTP method name like post put destroy", decorator=swagger_auto_schema(
   tags=["App name"], operation_description=docs['ViewName']['post']))
3. if you are overriding any method then you have to explicitly add on
   that view like this

@swagger_auto_schema(tags=["App name"], operation_description=docs['View Name']['post'])

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I found this package "drf-spectacular" which is much better and use openApi 3. It has what I want.